# Zend: Redirect to page after log in with a URL from email

Tags: zend-framework, forwarding

I am using Zend and I have an email sent to all members which contains a link to a Post. Only members logged in can comment but all guest can see it. Of course whoever is clicking on the link in the email should be able to comment straight away.
For this reason what I would like to find out is a way to check if a member clicking on the link is logged in or not:-

- if already logged in the URL in the email should take the member to the Post directly.
- if not logged in forward the member to the log in page and then to the proper URL containined in the link.

I hope I explained myself. Please ask me if not. Could someone please advise the best way to do it?

Thank you. F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function emailAction()
{
$loggedIn = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
if($loggedIn)
{
$this->_helper->_forward('post);
}else {

  $this->_helper->_forward('login');
}
}

public function loginAction()
{
 $success = new Zend_Session_Namespace('success');
 if(!isset($success->url)) 
{
  $success->url = $this->view->serverUrl(true);
}
 $form = new Login_Form();
if($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($_POST))
{
$this->_redirect($success->url);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a plugin and save the requested Uri in the session using:

```
$this->_session->lastUrl = $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

Then, after the user enters his credentials, redirect him to this saved URL.

Another option would be to save the url and add it as parameter to the next requests, like Google, Yahoo and SO do.